# Xpath Newb Needs Help Printing Parent/Path Tags in Output

Tags: xpath

I'm parsing XML files and paring the results down to a specific set of tags, but the output isn't  valid XML.

Here's the command I'm running to extract a small subset of tags under the path "joblist/job:"

```
xpath -q -e '/joblist/job/*[self::uuid or self::group or self::name or self::description or self::tags]'
```

Here's the output. Note that it's just printing the requested tags, and nothing "encasing" them:

```
<description>Validate a service by selecting an endpoint.</description>
<group>Validations/MyService</group>
<name>Transaction</name>
<tags>validations,MyService</tags>
<uuid>a6a32547-61ec-24bb-a424-faf4bc34f171</uuid>
```

xmllint doesn't parse this output:

```
-:4: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<group>Validations/MyService</group>
^
```

So I wonder then if I can include the parent tags, which would be:

```
<joblist>
  <job>
    <description>Validate a service by selecting an endpoint.</description>
    <group>Validations/MyService</group>
    <name>Transaction</name>
    <tags>validations,MyService</tags>
    <uuid>a6a32547-61ec-24bb-a424-faf4bc34f171</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Is this possible, or is there a better solution for what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: What is the input XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as Michael has pointed out, is that XPath, the language, is just not sufficiently expressive to perform the task you need. (It would I think be possible in XPath 3 but only awkwardly, and I think you are not running XPath 3 here).

On the bright side, this task is easily performed e.g. in XSLT, simply by embedding your existing XPath into a very simple XSLT stylesheet

```xml
<joblist xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <job>
    <xsl:copy-of select="
      /joblist/job/*[
        self::uuid or self::group or self::name or self::description or self::tags
      ]
    "/>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

See [section 2.3 "Literal Result Element as Stylesheet" of the XSLT spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#result-element-stylesheet) for the details of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

XPath is designed for locating information in existing documents, not for constructing new documents. You want XSLT or XQuery for that job.

Comment: Sure, but given that the tags I’m successfully printing exist within tags <joblist><job> in the original doc, is there parameter or query I can pass that would include those in the results?

Comment: The new document is different from the old document, and XPath can't construct new documents., even by reorganising information that's present in the old document.